# /etc/odbcinst.ini used by 64 and 32 bits applications

Tags: 64bit, 32bit, odbc

I have the following `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file

```
[root@]# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS odbc driver
#Driver=/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0
Driver=/usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
UsageCount=1
```

I have applications compiled for 64 and 32 bits.

```
[root@]# ldd prog_32 | grep odbc
        libodbc.so.2 => /lib/libodbc.so.2 (0xf7563000)
[root@]# ldd prog_64 | grep odbc
        libodbc.so.2 => /lib64/libodbc.so.2 (0x00007f6087202000)
```

As you probably noticed I have 2 entries in `odbcinst.ini` file for Driver, one for 32 bits and the other for 64. The problem is that if I run program compiled for 64 bits while the Driver is 32 bits or the other way around my program fails at run time with the error

```
OTL error message = [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so.0' : file not found
```

So I go and replace the Driver entry in the `odbcinst.ini` until next time it will happen to me which is quite frequent.

Is there a way to use 64 bit drive for 64 bits applications and 32 bits driver for 32 bits application without needing to comment out the entry in the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: Can you add a second entry: `"Driver64"`?

The equivalent section in  my config file in /etc.odbcinst.ini looks like this:

```
cat /etc/odbcinst.ini 
[TDSdriver]
Description=only MSSQL, not for Sybase
Driver64=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup64=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount=1
CPTimeout=5
CPReuse=
```

But I must confess currently my setup does not really work, (but it used to. I have forgotten many details about these issues)

Comment: The problem is that in `/etc/odbc.ini` I have `Driver = FreeTDS` and I don't know how to change it such way that both 64 and 32 bit applications will be able to use the correct driver with the same DSN